# React - Onselect doesnt show the selected value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get the selected value to show in the dropdown. I have 2 child components and a parent component. 
One child component has a dropdown and other displays graph based on the selected value. Everything is working fine. The selected value is going to the parent component and the other child component and the graph is drawn right. Just the selected value doesnt appear in the dropdown

Even the console.log shows the correct selected value. What am I missing.

```
export default class CustomGraphComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedOption: iconsData[0]
    };
}

handleSelect = (eventKey) => {
    this.props.onSelectOption(iconsData[eventKey]); 
    console.log(iconsData[eventKey]);
    this.setState({ selectedOption: iconsData[eventKey] });

}

render() {
    var {onSelectOption} = this.props;

    return (
        <div style={{paddingTop:20}} >
            <DropdownButton title ={this.state.selectedOption} onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
                {
                    iconsData.map((indexName, i) => {
                        return (
                            <MenuItem key={i} eventKey={i}>
                                {indexName}
                            </MenuItem>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </DropdownButton>

        </div>
    );
}
}
CustomGraphComponent.propTypes = {
    onSelectOption : PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: I think you set the value as state, you should set the key, 
this.setState({ selectedOption: eventKey });

Comment: No I actually want to show the value in the dropdown. Anyways tried this too. Didnt work.

Comment: Are you setting the right prop of DropdownButton? Have you tried setting the value instead?